# How to print a specific part of an exception error

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to handle an exception from an API I am using and would like to send a message to the user with a specific part of the error That is being sent. How would I separate it?

The result of printing the exception looks like this:

```
NoneFull details: [{'code': 10010, 'detail': 'Originating number listed in do-not-originate registry D46', 'title': None}]
```

I am trying to print only the 'detail' : part of the exception.

Comment: did you try like `[0].detail` on full details exception? also share full code block

Comment: Is that the string representation of the exception, or does the exception have a list-valued attribute?

Comment: All I've done is 
```
except api.error.PermissionError as e:
print(e)
```

This is the first time I have ever used except in my code so not really sure what you mean by the [0].detail.

Answer (score 0):

This should work because it seems that `e` is a `list[dict]` in your case:

```
try:
    pass    # Your code...
except api.error.PermissionError as e:
    print(e.args[0][0]['detail'])
```

If you added manually the `[]` then maybe you will have to remove one of the `[0]`.

Comment: That is giving me TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: This is from the developer page on my api.

ERROR FORMATTING
We include known causes and possible solutions so that API users can write logic to handle errors intelligently and debug quickly. When one or more errors are present, the top-level key in the response will be errors and not data. The value for errors will always be an array, and there will always be at least one error present when this is returned.

Comment: Without more explicit information about the API will **not** be possible to fix this, I can just give you a few hints: `e.args` is a tuple, and the `list[dict]` that you provided in your description is the first element, hence my proposal of `e.args[0][0]['detail']`. The error you are mentioning above means that somehow you are accessing a `str` instead of a `tuple` and/or a `list`.

Comment: for the sake of curiosity, try `e.args[0][0][0]` and try different values for the last index.

Comment: It printed  a single letter "N" using 0 any other number shows "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: indeed, it is a string in there, then does `e.args[0][0]` prints the message from your description?

Comment: `
e.args[0][0]
`
Also prints the letter 'n'

Comment: You have to debug then, or share more details of the API, sorry

Comment: An example from the api of an output for an error they posted would be. 

```lang-py
{
  "errors":[
    {
      "code":"10006",
      "title":"Invalid resource ID",
      "detail":"The provided resource ID was invalid",
      "source":{
        "pointer":"/id"
      },
      "meta":{
        "url":"URL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```